# HVAC unit keeps tripping breaker

Tags: hvac, circuit-breaker

[image]

had a short in the float switch wire( its all chewed up from rats) the short blew the 5A fuse . I spliced the wire and reattached it to its self in 3 places. this got it working but now its tripping the double 60 breaker after like 5-10 minutes.

images hosted at imgbb(blaze2248)

Comment: can you share the image somewhere we don't need to register to?

Comment: its no longer tripping the breaker after the 3rd splice but I found a place that has the safe T switch in stock